# Particular Split Java

Tags: java, split

I'm a new programmer, I have a problem with this code.

```
public static String getString() throws IOException {

    String content = null;
    File folder = new File("C:\\Soluzioni.txt");
    content = FileUtils.readFileToString(folder) + "\n";
    String remainingString = content.substring(content.indexOf("["),
            content.lastIndexOf("]") + 1);
    System.out.println(remainingString);    // Output 1.
    return remainingString;

}
```

When I use this method

```
public static String[] arg() throws IOException {
    String[] strArray = getString().split("\\s+,0");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));  //Output 2.
    return strArray;
}
```

My Problem is this:

- First output: `[-2,-8] [8,-4] [-3,2] [4,-1]`
- Second output: `[[-2,-8] [8,-4] [-3,2] [4,-1]]`.

Now I would like to have the same output (identical). How can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: what is wrong? can you add Soluzioni.txt too?

Comment: of course, Soluzioni.txt is [-2,-8] [8,-4] [-3,2] [4,-1]

Comment: the `[]` are added by Arrays.toString. You don't have it in your array

Comment: @SnakeDoc Why? It's italian (or another language with the same word)

Comment: Ok, sorry for idiot question. I'm so noob. Thank you.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno it reminds me of "pepperoni", which is so delicious!  (I said this in jest obviously lol)

Comment: @SnakeDoc ahah yup. Anyway Lorenz, no problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Arrays.toString and loop over the contents of the array yourself printing the strings individually.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting different outputs is because you're printing 2 different things:

Output 1:

```
System.out.println(remainingString);
```

Output 2:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
```

You are printing 2 different objects. So you have 2 choices:

1) Avoid the problem entirely. Print your string without splitting it:

```
System.out.println(getString());
```

2) Format it yourself. This actually presents 2 suboptions.

a) Get a third party library like [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) that includes a `join` function to make your life easier. This is probably what you want to do if this is real world code and you can't do option 1; don't reinvent the wheel.

b) Write code to do the join yourself. This isn't all that hard. You have a list of strings; you just need to loop over them and add a space after each one except the last one (or remove the space after the last one). I'll leave writing this code as an exercise for your since this is what you would do if you're doing homework.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to manually drop the square brackets.

```
String output = Arrays.toString(strArray);
System.out.println(output.substring(1, output.length() -2);
```